get User inputs in Webview, React native
the webpage im loading in my webview needs an audio input but the webview throws "getUserMedia not supported in your browser" error.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const HeyComponent = ({ customKnowledgeBaseId }) => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(Dimensions.get('window'));

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({ window }) => {
      setDimensions(window);
    });

    return () => subscription?.remove();
  }, []);

  const generateHtmlContent = (knowledgeBaseId) => {
    const baseUrl = 'example.com';
    const shareParams = `xyz`;
    const url = `example.com`;

    return `
      </html>
    `;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{ html: generateHtmlContent(customId) }}
        style={styles.webview}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        mixedContentMode="always"
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default HeyComponent;

please give a general solution this is an Expo react app.
i have seen some solutions here but they are not generic

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const App = () => {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: `
          <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Type something"/>
          <button onclick="window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.getElementById('input').value)">
            Send Input
          </button>
        ` }}
        onMessage={(event) => setUserInput(event.nativeEvent.data)}
      />
      <Text>User Input: {userInput}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

